# "locate" returns relative instead of absolute paths

Tags: terminal, search, path, zsh, alias

I have the following entry in root's `crontab`:

```
0 */4 * * * cd /private/var/root && ./locate.updatedb
```

I have an alias for `locate` in `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias locate='locate -d /var/db/locate.database'
```

When I do a "`locate Table_Synthesis_GREY_`" , in all the full paths of files found, the first slash of the path indicating the file system root is missing. Here is a sample of the ouput:

```
Users/henry/Projects/JUNK_AND_OLD/Travail_9_Paper_Combinaison_et_Methode_des_biais_communs_pour_ma_These_SAUVEGARDES/TABLES_FLAT_AND_NON_FLAT_to_include_into_my_Phd_paper_LAST/Table_Synthesis_Main_05_AOUT_2020/temp/Table_Synthesis_GREY_IMPORTANT_SAVE_5_AOUT_2020.run.xml
Users/henry/Projects/JUNK_AND_OLD/Travail_9_Paper_Combinaison_et_Methode_des_biais_communs_pour_ma_These_SAUVEGARDES/TABLES_FLAT_AND_NON_FLAT_to_include_into_my_Phd_paper_LAST/Table_Synthesis_Main_05_AOUT_2020/temp/Table_Synthesis_GREY_IMPORTANT_SAVE_5_AOUT_2020.tex
Users/henry/Projects/JUNK_AND_OLD/Travail_9_Paper_Combinaison_et_Methode_des_biais_communs_pour_ma_These_SAUVEGARDES/TABLES_FLAT_AND_NON_FLAT_to_include_into_my_Phd_paper_LAST/Table_Synthesis_Main_05_AOUT_2020/temp/Table_Synthesis_GREY_IMPORTANT_SAVE_5_AOUT_2020.zip
Users/henry/Projects/JUNK_AND_OLD/Travail_9_Paper_Combinaison_et_Methode_des_biais_communs_pour_ma_These_SAUVEGARDES/TABLES_FLAT_AND_NON_FLAT_to_include_into_my_Phd_paper_LAST/Table_Synthesis_Main_05_AOUT_2020/temp/Table_Synthesis_GREY_IMPORTANT_SAVE_5_AOUT_2020_ORIGINAL_INTO_zip_here.pdf
Users/henry/Projects/JUNK_AND_OLD/Travail_9_Paper_Combinaison_et_Methode_des_biais_communs_pour_ma_These_SAUVEGARDES/TABLES_FLAT_AND_NON_FLAT_to_include_into_my_Phd_paper_LAST/Table_Synthesis_Main_AFTER_05_AOUT_2020/FLAT_Synthesis/Table_Synthesis_GREY_FLAT.docx
```

How can I have paths output as absolute paths, i.e. starting at `/Users`? The desired output is

```
/Users/henry/Projects/JUNK_AND_OLD/Travail_9_Paper_Combinaison_et_Methode_des_biais_communs_pour_ma_These_SAUVEGARDES/TABLES_FLAT_AND_NON_FLAT_to_include_into_my_Phd_paper_LAST/Table_Synthesis_Main_AFTER_05_AOUT_2020/FLAT_Synthesis/Table_Synthesis_GREY_FLAT.docx
```

as opposed to

```
Users/henry/Projects/JUNK_AND_OLD/Travail_9_Paper_Combinaison_et_Methode_des_biais_communs_pour_ma_These_SAUVEGARDES/TABLES_FLAT_AND_NON_FLAT_to_include_into_my_Phd_paper_LAST/Table_Synthesis_Main_AFTER_05_AOUT_2020/FLAT_Synthesis/Table_Synthesis_GREY_FLAT.docx
```

**UPDATE 1:** I have copied `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` into my home root, that is in `/var/root/` . I did that since I could not modify the `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` file, even `being root` or with `sudo`.

So in this other file `/var/root/locate.updatedb`, I could do the modification :

```
if [ "$(id -u)" = "99" ]; then
```

instead of initially :

```
if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
```

What do you think about this trick ? and mostly why I have not the first slash displayed when results into my `/Users/henry/`.

```
0 */4 * * * cd /private/var/root ; /bin/sh locate.updatedb
```

but issue remains.

By the way, if results are located into /Applications or other main directories **but not systematically**, the first slash is well displayed.

Anyone has a clue ?

Comment: Is that a different `locate.updatedb` from the system one? How did you configure it?

Comment: I half suspect that you may get better answers on unix.stackexchange.com. When asking there, I suggest that you focus on how it seems to return relative instead of absolute paths

Comment: Please don't put part of the question into the bounty message, it's hard to read there and a lot of people will just ignore it. Edit the question instead to contain all relevant details.

Comment: Also, you seem to ask several questions at once. What is the role of the test if the id of the current user is 99?

Comment: @nohillside I have change id of the current to not be dependent of `nobody` user default user that doesn't index all the directories by default. I think there is no link between this change and my issue here.